# flutter_background_service returning an error MissingPluginException

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a background process to update fcm token and send it to my api. Here is what i do

```
void onStart() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
  service.setForegroundMode(true);
  Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 15), (timer) async {
    Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
    try {
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
      if (!(await service.isServiceRunning())) timer.cancel();

      if (prefs.getString("member_id") != null) {
        _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) async {
          print("TOKEN ");
          print(token);
          // await ProfileApi().updateToken(prefs.getString("member_id"), token);
        });
        service.sendData(
          {
            "current_date": DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
          },
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      await ProfileApi()
          .updateToken(prefs.getString("member_id"), e.toString());

      print(e);
    }
  });
}
```

My `onStart()` is top level widget. When i run it, it is returning this error

> Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found
> for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)

How i can fix it ?

Comment: Did you try to run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` after adding it to yaml file? Hot restart and hot reload does not work to load all necessary library files if that library is new in project.

Comment: Well, the error because i call the `SharedPreference` on `onStart `.

Answer (score 0):

That generally happens when you add a new plugin in your project and you do Hot Restart and Hot Reload.

The plugin contains the native code like in ios swift and android java/kotlin so you need to stop the application and Run again.

If the issue still persists then do flutter clean and run again.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  the error because i call the SharedPreference on onStart. I know that error same as when i adding new plugin

Answer (score 0):

i saw in your comment above that you have this error when adding any new plugin.

as I a faced before.. this error comes from adding
Facebbok login plugin or google login plugin or apple login with out completing all steps in order to make those plugins work.

So if you have used any of them, complete the setup as explained in each ones

Or check if you have any plugin that you didn't complete it's setup

Hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found like your issue and solution.

> Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found
> for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)

https://fluttercorner.com/flutter-unhandled-exception-missingpluginexceptionno-implementation-found-for/

I think it helps your case.

```
/android/app/build.gradle

...
    buildTypes {
        release {
           ...
           shrinkResources false
           minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}
'''
```